# How to program a Neo4j Service Manager?

Tags: c#, powershell, neo4j

I am trying to write a Neo4j service manager program in C# that can start and stop local graph databases using the current Neo4j version, 3.3.5. The program should replicate the functionality of the discontinued `Neo4j-ce.exe` program. The program will call the same PowerShell commands that are in the `Neo4j.bat` file. This is the first PowerShell script I have tried to write.

So far, on start-up the program issues many exception errors that end with "Cannot find or open the PDB file." When I run the PowerShell instance code, security exceptions are thrown ...

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
```

... Yet the `PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count` is zero.

`Neo4j.bat` contains this call to PowerShell:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "try { Unblock-File -Path '%~dp0Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {};Import-Module '%~dp0Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j %*)"
```

`Neo4jServiceManager.exe` contains this button event:

```
private void btnNeo4jStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create runspace to be used by PowerShell instance.
    Runspace myRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    myRunspace.Open();

    // Start PowerShell instance.
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // Add runspace to PowerShell instance.
        PowerShellInstance.Runspace = myRunspace;

        // Add command to pipeline.
        // Import module: Neo4j-Management.psd1 and execute Invoke-Neo4j cmdlet.
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"C:\; cd C:\neo4j-community-3.3.5; SETLOCAL; try { Unblock-File -Path 'C:\neo4j-community-3.3.5\bin\Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {}; Exit ('C:\neo4j-community-3.3.5\bin\Neo4j-Management\Invoke-Neo4j.psd1 install-service')");

        // Invoke execution on the pipeline (and collect output).
        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

        // Loop through each output object item.
        foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
        {
            // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
            // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
            if (outputItem != null)
            {
                //TODO: do something with the output item 
                // outputItem.BaseOBject
            }
        }

        // Check the other output streams (for example, the error stream).
        // If PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count = 1, then
        // PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error[0].CategoryInfo returns information.
        if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            // error records were written to the error stream.
            // do something with the items found.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at the commands you're issuing in PowerShell (example: `setlocal` is not a PowerShell command but rather a `cmd.exe` command). Also, `%~dp` syntax is `cmd.exe` also. The point is that PowerShell is not a `cmd.exe` drop-in replacement; the concepts and syntax are different.

Comment: How am I supposed to know that EXE and BAT file names are supposed to be treated as "code" with code highlighted? I cannot find a Stack Overflow style guide. There is a lot of HOW-to-format information, but not WHAT to format rules.

Comment: My apologies, Bill. My previous comment had nothing to do with what you wrote, which I should have said. I was trying to reply to the editors who made format changes made to my original post. I couldn't find a way to write to the editors, or thank them, or get advice. So I made a comment, hoping that the editors would see that.

Comment: As you point out, SETLOCAL has no meaning for PowerShell, so I removed it from the script. If you look at my original post, you can see that I replaced the %~dp expansion in the batch file with the full path name in the PowerShell script. ("CD" seems to work in PowerShell.) I'll try to work out a series of commands that work at the PowerShell prompt, then put them in script. If I get it to work, I'll post the answer. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: `cd` is an alias for `Set-Location` in PowerShell. The command is available, but it does not work identically to the `cmd.exe` `cd` command. I would recommend studying PowerShell first before diving in too much further; it will likely save you a lot of frustration.